# Testing for treatment differences in a problem involving repeated measures

Tags: r, mixed-model, anova, repeated-measures

I am having trouble choosing the right statistical test for my data analysis.

Every patient undergoes a stress condition and other five normal conditions. For each patient and for each condition I measure the blood flow velocity. The measures are thus repeated.

Which statistic test should be used to compare the difference between different normal conditions and between all conditions?

Currently, I have observed values for 7 patients, but the study is undergoing and the number of patients will likely increase.

Comment: I would not expect to gain much insight with only  7 observations. Having said this, do all patients undergo all settings 1-5?

Comment: I agree - there will eventually come more data. Yes, all patients under go measurement 1 (under stress) and measurement 2(under normal circumstance) in all settings (1-5)

Comment: You can't really choose a statistical test until you pose the questions you want the statistical method to answer.
Are you also measuring blood flow twice in the same patient without stress (or both with)?

Comment: Maybe if i formulate it different: I observe measurement 1(blood velocity under stress) and measurement 2(blood velocity under rest) in the same patient under setting 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5.  

This is done for each for the participants

Comment: @Sophie my question is: do the patients undergo all the rest conditions?

Comment: @HarveyMotulsky I guess the answer is yes, the OP is dealing with repeated measures.

Comment: Yes repeated measures. so two measurements at two times with two conditions. How much of the difference is due to time (the seond mesurement may be consistently different than the first) vs. condition?

Comment: Two measurements that are done within seconds apart under 5 different settings.

I want to compare the difference in blood velocity under stress and under rest in all 5 settings.

Comment: Ok but you didn't answer my question: do the patients undergo all the rest conditions/settings? Or do they undergo just one setting each?

Comment: @utobi Yes, they all undergo the rest and stress in each setting/condition

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your question to improve readability. Feel free to change it at will.

Answer (score 1):

**The problem**
We have a certain number of patients, and each of them undergoes six, let's say treatments:

- stress
- normal condition 1
- normal condition 2
- normal condition 3
- normal condition 4
- normal condition 5

The variable being measured is `blood flow velocity` (bfv) and the aim is to compare the bfv in the six treatments.

A standard way to solve this problem is by applying a linear mixed effects model in which you consider treatment as fixed-effect with six levels and a random intercept for each unit. As a first step you test if there is an overall significant effect and if there is such an effect, you can then apply post-hoc pairwise comparison tests.

Here is a simple `R` code that does this using simulated and **not necessarily realistic** data.

```
# nr. of patients
N <- 30

set.seed(1)
bfv_stress <- rnorm(N,50, sd=1)
bfv_rest1 <- rnorm(N,20, sd=1.1)
bfv_rest2 <- rnorm(N,21, sd=1.2)
bfv_rest3 <- rnorm(N,21.2, sd=1.3)
bfv_rest4 <- rnorm(N,20.5, sd=1.3)
bfv_rest5 <- rnorm(N,25, sd=1.8)
    my_long_data <- data.frame(bfv = c(bfv_stress,bfv_rest1,
                                   bfv_rest2,bfv_rest3,
                                   bfv_rest4,bfv_rest5),
                           treatment = factor(c(rep("stress", N),
                                         rep("rest1", N),
                                         rep("rest2", N),
                                         rep("rest3", N),
                                         rep("rest4", N),
                                         rep("rest5", N)))
                           )
my_long_data$patient_id <- rep(1:N, 6)
my_long_data$treatment <- relevel(my_long_data$treatment, ref = 6)

library(nlme)
mod <- lme(fixed = bfv~treatment, random = ~1|patient_id, 
           data = my_long_data)
```

To check for an overall effect do

```
> anova(mod)
            numDF denDF  F-value p-value
(Intercept)     1   145 80633.15  <.0001
treatment       5   145  2683.89  <.0001
```

In this (fake) example we see that there is an overall effect so it is worth considering pairwise differences. For this, you can just look at the estimate of the individual fixed-effects

```
> summary(mod)
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
  Data: my_long_data 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  606.6822 631.9546 -295.3411

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | patient_id
         (Intercept) Residual
StdDev: 5.123981e-05 1.245806

Fixed effects:  bfv ~ treatment 
                   Value Std.Error  DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept)     50.08246 0.2274520 145 220.18910       0
treatmentrest1 -29.93641 0.3216657 145 -93.06681       0
treatmentrest2 -28.95012 0.3216657 145 -90.00064       0
treatmentrest3 -28.73513 0.3216657 145 -89.33225       0
treatmentrest4 -30.01149 0.3216657 145 -93.30025       0
treatmentrest5 -24.65585 0.3216657 145 -76.65054       0
 Correlation: 
               (Intr) trtmn1 trtmn2 trtmn3 trtmn4
treatmentrest1 -0.707                            
treatmentrest2 -0.707  0.500                     
treatmentrest3 -0.707  0.500  0.500              
treatmentrest4 -0.707  0.500  0.500  0.500       
treatmentrest5 -0.707  0.500  0.500  0.500  0.500

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
        Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
-2.49158680 -0.65489515 -0.05844344  0.53399982  2.99224391 

Number of Observations: 180
Number of Groups: 30
```

The output above shows the estimated average `bfv` in the normal conditions minus the average in the stress condition (the reference level). Here we see that all normal conditions are statistically different from rest. You can test for differences between two rest conditions by changing the reference level to your desired rest condition and re-fit the model.

The mixed model is useful here because it takes care of the possible dependence between observations, where the dependence arises from the fact that units are treated repeatedly. Linear regression with uncorrelated errors, as suggested by another answer, ignores this dependence; see, e.g., Chapter 1 of Demidenko, *Mixed Models: Theory and Applications with R*, 2nd Edition, Wiley, ISBN: 978-1-118-09157-9, 2013.

**Remark** The output of `lme` does not correct for the multiplicity issue. One way to apply the multiplicity correction is to extract the p-values and apply an adjustment method such as Benjamini-Hochberg or Holm, all implemented in the `R` function `p.adjust` (`?p.adjust`).

Another possible solution would be via permutation testing methods. You can find several threads on this topic by searching the site.

Comment: Within each treatment group there is no repeated measurements, so by conditioning on the group, the dependence issue disappears and linear regression with uncorrelated errors works just fine (cause errors within groups are uncorrelated). Please think about that more thoroughly before disputing my answer.

Comment: @AminShn think about patient 1, he gives value under stress, under rest 1, ..., and rest 5. The point is: do you think these six values are generated independently? My contention is they aren't since all these values have something in common, they come from the same patient, patient 1.

Comment: Your question is irrelevant because the model's assumption is about conditional dependence and not independence in marginal distribution of the response. Again this is the model assumption y|treatment ~ N(Mu_treatment, sigma) which you have not challenged.

Comment: we do not seem to understand eachother and our conversation is fruitless so I'm going to stop this conversation here. best

Answer (score 0):

Since the patients in each treatment cohort are identical, I don't think you need a mixed model (as opposed to utobi's answer). Instead you can simply perform pairwise one-sample t-test between the treatments (even this is not my favourite solution). But I would simply use the lm() function to estimate each treatments expected value of the target and then considering the confidence intervals I would compare the groups using the GGally package. Here is how I do it:

```r
# nr. of patients
N <- 30

# --- using a modified version of the simulated data by utobi
set.seed(1)
bfv_stress <- rnorm(N,50, sd=10)
bfv_rest1 <- rnorm(N,2, sd=7)
bfv_rest2 <- rnorm(N,3, sd=10)
bfv_rest3 <- rnorm(N,0, sd=15)
bfv_rest4 <- rnorm(N,0, sd=16)
bfv_rest5 <- rnorm(N,-1, sd=17)

my_long_data <- data.frame(bfv = c(bfv_stress,bfv_rest1,
                                   bfv_rest2,bfv_rest3,
                                   bfv_rest4,bfv_rest5),
                           treatment = c(rep("stress", N),
                                         rep("rest1", N),
                                         rep("rest2", N),
                                         rep("rest3", N),
                                         rep("rest4", N),
                                         rep("rest5", N)
                           ))
my_long_data$patient_id <- rep(1:N, 6)


# Fitting the model
lm.fit = lm(bfv ~ -1 + treatment, data = my_long_data)

# Visualising the results
GGally::ggcoef_model(lm.fit)
```

And here is the resulting plot:

[image]

From this plot you can see that the stress treatment is significantly different than the rest. Their confidence intervals do not overlap and if you perform a hypothesis test you will get significant result for $\alpha = 5\%$.

Comment: Sorry to disagree but your answer is not correct. The observations are not independent, e.g. we have repeated measures here since the patient is "treated" repeatedly. You could apply pairwise paired t-tests but, only after a significant ANOVA with repeated measures, which brings you back to my answer.

Comment: @utobi My model's assumption is "y|treatment ~ N(treatment, sigma^2)" which holds. Conditional on the treatment, residuals are independent.

Comment: how many observations do you have in your lm model? Don’t you see that each unit appears in the rows of your data six times? Having said this, do you still think individuals are jointly indipendent?

Comment: @utobi Look at the formula, conditioning on the cohorts resolves your concern. Again the model's assumption is "y|treatment ~ N(Mu_treatment, sigma^2)", if you have anything against this assumption I am all ear.

Comment: @utobi You might want to check this post, confirms that my approach is not wrong: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/604630/estimating-and-comparing-treatment-effects-with-participants-that-have-repeated

Comment: while I do see that including fixed-effects may be the solution (which you are not doing in your answer!) the problem with the fixed-effects approach is that is kind of overkill for a large number of units. However, the random vs fixed-effects debate is going...

Comment: The first sentence says: "That is a perfectly fine way to estimate the treatment effect." which is similar to my solution here. Noah thinks adding fixed effects could only help with precision but I think that could come at a cost similar to what you just said. But the dependence issue that you're concerned with is irrelevant.